# Отображать url страниц без расширения в любом случае. htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, url, редирект

Проблема в следующем:
Url страниц отображаются без расширения ".php" с помощью такой вот штуки:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /$1.php
```

url страниц выглядят следующим образом:

```
http://site.ru/page
```

Но если напрямую в url написать адрес страницы с расширением ".php", то url будет таким:

```
http://site.ru/page.php
```

Как это исправить? Т.е. чтобы url страницы в любом случае отображался без расширения(без ".php").

Answer (score 0):

Я могу заблуждаться, но как раз эта строка и добавляет .php в конец адреса страницы, поэтому от неё лучше избавиться

```
#-RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /$1.php
```

Добавляем условие выборки страниц с расширением php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.php$
```

Здесь можно добавить дополнительные условия. Например, если мы хотим, чтобы редирект не отрабатывал на каких-то определенных файлах. Это уже на ваше личное усмотрение.

Пишем правила перенаправления. Все страницы, которые оканчиваются на .php будут перенаправлены на адреса, который это расширение не содержит.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```